# NVDA not reading aria-label on div

Tags: html, accessibility, nvda

I have a div element with `role="listitem"`. It contains multiple divs with some text inside. When he outer div is focused, I want a custom aria-label to be read instead of the inner texts. Here is my sample code:

```
<div role="listitem" aria-label="Hello World" tab-index="0">
  <div> A </div>  <div> b </div>  <div> c </div>  <div> d </div>
</div>
```

On JAWS and Narrator, it works as expected. On NVDA, it's reading the inner text.

On changing outer div to anchor tag, NVDA is reading correct `aria-label`, but I cannot do that in prod code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NVDA seems to honor the `aria-label` for some roles but not others.  It works for `button` and `menuitem`, it reads both the `aria-label` and the nested `<div>`s for `checkbox`, and ignores `aria-label` for `listitem`, as you mentioned.

This seems to be a current bug.  See https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/7807